# Finding value in unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

I am using Boost unordered_map. I have a key value pair for each entry. How could I determine whether a particular value exist in the map? (I don't want to create another unordered_map which stored the value as key and key as value)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

How about the following:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map_type;
typedef std::unordered_map<int,std::string>::value_type map_value_type;

map_type m;

if (m.end() != find_if(m.begin(),m.end(),[](const map_value_type& vt)
                                           { return vt.second == "abc"; }
                                           ))
   std::cout << "Value found." << std::end;
else
   std::cout << "Value NOT found." << std::end;
```

Or using an external variable that is captured:

```
std::string value = "abc";
if (m.end() != find_if(m.begin(),m.end(),[&value](const map_value_type& vt)
                                                 { return vt.second == value; }))
   std::cout << "Value found." << std::end;
else
   std::cout << "Value NOT found." << std::end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the lambda expression, how could I pass argument in if the return vt.second == "abc" in which the "abc" is an argument that need to be passed in?

Comment: I've updated the example above. In short you capture the variable from the scope in which the lambda is defined.

Comment: Nice answer, requires C++0x (or extensions to C++03) though.

Answer (score 7):

Boost has the [Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html), which is a bidirectional map (ie, keys and values both refer to each other). This sounds more appropriate for your needs than the `unordered_map`.

Comment: Doesn't OP say they don't want a reverse map?  Although they don't justify why.

Comment: Little kids don't want a trip to the dentist, but good parenting does it anyway.

Comment: @ephemient: I think the OP doesn't want to have to maintain a separate data structure (more likely). Therefore if it comes all packaged, I can't see why there would be an issue (since the equality is defined anyway for `value`).

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate over all the elements in the `unordered_map` and see if the given value exists.

The `std::find_if` algorithm with a custom predicate can be used to simplify this.

Comment: Custom predicate?  Everything you need is already in STL.  `compose1(bind2nd(equal_to<Value>(), value), select2nd<pair<Key, Value> >())`

Comment: @ephemient: That is neither simple nor readable.  (Also, `select2nd`, while part of the STL, is not a part of the C++ standard library)

Comment: @ephemient: That is one of the worst uses of STL I have ever seen.