# map.find() and map.end() iterators are said to be incompatible?

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I am using the map.find(key) and map.end() functions in an if statement:

```
if( p_Repos->returnTypeMap().find(tc[0]) != p_Repos->returnTypeMap().end() )
```

But it doesn't work, and I get a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error that tells me "Expression: list iterators incompatible".  tc[0] is just a string, and the key position in my map is a string.

But, they should be compatible, right?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Edit:  Based on an answer found here: [Finding value in unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395050/finding-value-in-unordered-map/7840078#7840078), I'm lead to believe this should def work.

Second Edit:
Here is the returnTypeMap() function:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> returnTypeMap()
{
      return typeTable;
}
```

Here is the definition of my map:

```
std::unordered_map <std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> typeTable;
```

Comment: Does `returnTypeMap()` return by value? If so, each iterator is pointing in to a completely different `map`.

Comment: Mankarse, I am not sure what you mean.  Should I set a local map = to the map I am storing in my p_Repos object?

Comment: Maybe you should use `if( p_Repos->returnTypeMap().count(tc[0]) > 0 )` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning the `map` by value, so each call evaluates to a completely different `map`. Iterators in to different containers are not compatible, and attempting to compare them has undefined behaviour.

Try changing your code to return by `const` reference:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> const& 
returnTypeMap() const
{
    return typeTable;
}
```

or make a local copy of the map and call `find` and `end` on the single local copy:

```
auto typeTable{p_Repos->returnTypeMap()};
if (typeTable.find(tc[0]) != typeTable.end()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll make a local copy, as I am not very good at using the const qualifier.  If you wouldn't mind being more specific with how I would use the const qualifier, I might try to implement that.

Comment: @traggatmot: The important part isn't the `const` qualifier, but the fact that you would be returning by reference (and so would not be making copies of `typeTable` when returning it).