# c++ - unordered_map complexity

Tags: c++, hashtable, complexity-theory, unordered-map

I need to create a lookup function where a (X,Y) pair corresponds to a specific Z value.  One major requirement for this is that I need to do it in as close to O(1) complexity as I can.  My plan is to use an unordered_map.

I generally do not use a hash table for lookup, as the lookup time has never been important to me.  Am I correct in thinking that as long as I built the unordered_map with no collisions, my lookup time will be O(1)?

My concern then is what the complexity becomes if there the key is not present in the unordered map.  If I use unordered_map::find():, for example, to determine whether a key is present in my hash table, how will it go about giving me an answer?  Does it actually iterate over all the keys?

I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard more or less requires using buckets for collision
resolution, which means that the actual look up time will
probably be linear with respect to the number of elements in the
bucket, regardless of whether the element is present or not.
It's possible to make it O(lg N), but it's not usually done,
because the number of elements in the bucket *should* be small,
if the hash table is being used correctly.

To ensure that the number of elements in a bucket is small, you
must ensure that the hashing function is effective.  What
effective means depends on the types and values being hashed.
(The MS implementation uses FNV, which is one of the best 
generic hashs around, but if you have special knowledge of the
actual data you'll be seeing, you might be able to do better.)
Another thing which can help reduce the number of elements per
bucket is to force more buckets or use a smaller load factor.
For the first, you can pass the minimum initial number of
buckets as an argument to the constructor.  If you know the
total number of elements that will be in the map, you can
control the load factor this way.  You can also forse a minumum
number of buckets once the table has been filled, by calling
`rehash`.  Otherwise, there is a function
`std::unordered_map<>::max_load_factor` which you can use.  It
is not guaranteed to do anything, but in any reasonable
implementation, it will.  Note that if you use it on an already
filled `unordered_map`, you'll probably have to call
`unordered_map<>::rehash` afterwards.

(There are several things I don't understand about the standard
unordered_map: why the load factor is a `float`, instead of
`double`; why it's not required to have an effect; and why it
doesn't automatically call `rehash` for you.)

Answer (score 6):

As with any hash table, worst case is always linear complexity (*Edit: if you built the map without any collisions like you stated in your original post, then you'll never see this case*):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/

> **Complexity**
>   Average case: constant. 
>   Worst case: linear in container size.
>
> **Return Value**
>   An iterator to the element, if the specified key value is found, or unordered_map::end if the specified key is not found in the container.

However, because an unordered_map can only contain unique keys, you will see average complexity of constant time (container first checks hash index, and then iterates over values at that index).

I think the documentation for [unordered_map::count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/count/) function is more informative:

> Searches the container for elements whose key is k and returns the
>   number of elements found. Because unordered_map containers do not
>   allow for duplicate keys, this means that the function actually
>   returns 1 if an element with that key exists in the container, and
>   zero otherwise.

Comment: I am now confused by jakar's answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395050/finding-value-in-unordered-map

I would interpret this comment to mean it can be accomplished.  Is that not the case then?

Comment: @user1764386: Well, find has to return *something* if it can't return you an iterator to your value, so unordered_map::end was the best choice.

Comment: thank you for the help.  I meant that I am slightly confused by his answer because I interpreted it to mean that the complexity will be better than O(N) if the key is not in the unordered_map.

Comment: @user1764386 on average it will be. If you see the unlikely worst case of all your inputs hashing to the same value, then the data structure must iterate over the entire list.

Comment: Would you mind explaining in more detail?  Can I avoid having any two keys mapping to the same value?  I am building the unordered_map at one time based on input data.  I am never adding to it later.

Comment: @user1764386:In the worst case, no. This all comes down to the hashing function that you use. If you'd like, you can provide unordered_map with your own hashing function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/). Google hashing functions for more information on them.

Answer (score 5):

To have no collisions in a hashed data structure is incredibly difficult (if not impossible for a given hash function and any kind of data). It would also require a table size exactly equal to the number of keys. No, it does not need to be that strict. As long as the hash function distributes the values in a relatively uniform way, you will have `O(1)` lookup complexity.

Hash tables are generally just arrays with linked lists taking care of the collisions (this is the chaining method - there are other methods, but this is likely the most utilized way of dealing with collisions). Thus, to find if a value is contained within a bucket, it will have to (potentially) iterate over all the values in that bucket. So if the hash function gives you a uniform distribution, and there are `N` buckets, and a total of `M` values, there should be (on average) `M/N` values per bucket. As long as this value is not too large, this allows `O(1)` lookup.

So, as a bit of a long winded answer to your question, as long as the hashing function is reasonable, you will get `O(1)` lookup, with it having to iterate over (on average) `O(M/N)` keys to give you a "negative" result.