# Complexity Reduction to O(n) Over Multiple Simultaeneous Vector Iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I have 2 string vectors with the following content:

```
tokens: name name place thing thing
u_tokens: name place thing
```

Now my task is to simultaneously loop through both these vectors and find the occurrence of each word and store it in a third vector. Here's a minimal working implementation that I did (my task doesn't mention about duplicates so I did not consider removing it) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> counts;
    vector<string> tokens;
    vector<string> u_tokens;

    tokens.push_back("name");
    tokens.push_back("name");
    tokens.push_back("place");
    tokens.push_back("thing");
    tokens.push_back("thing");
    u_tokens.push_back("name");
    u_tokens.push_back("place");
    u_tokens.push_back("thing");

    string temp;
    int temp_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = tokens[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < u_tokens.size(); j++)
        {
            if(temp == u_tokens[j])
            {
                temp_count++;
            }
        }

        temp = tokens[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < tokens.size(); k++)
        {
            if (temp == tokens[k])
            {
                temp_count++;
            }
        }
        counts.push_back(temp_count);
        temp_count = 0;
    }

    for (vector<int>::const_iterator i = counts.begin(); i != counts.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << "  ";
    return 0;
}
```

However, I noticed, this obviously has a `O(n^2)` complexity. How can I reduce it to `O(n)`? Is it possible?

Regards.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) time if you first construct a _trie_ data structure to use as your word dictionary.  Or you can put the words into a `std::multiset` for something like O(n.log.n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

void CountOccurences(const vector<string>& input, unordered_map<string, size_t>& occurences)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        occurences[input[i]]++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> tokens;
    vector<string> u_tokens;
    unordered_map<string, size_t> occurences;

    tokens.push_back("name");
    tokens.push_back("name");
    tokens.push_back("place");
    tokens.push_back("thing");
    tokens.push_back("thing");
    u_tokens.push_back("name");
    u_tokens.push_back("place");
    u_tokens.push_back("thing");

    CountOccurences(tokens, occurences);
    CountOccurences(u_tokens, occurences);

    for (auto i : occurences)
        cout << i.first << "=" << i.second << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Use `std::unordered_map` as O(1) access container to create O(N) solution. In cost of memory of course.

Link to online compiled [program](http://cpp.sh/2iiqh)

Comment: I don't think that we can say that `std::unordered_map` as O(1). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470948/c-unordered-map-complexity. It's more O(log n) or O(n log n).

Comment: @Stargateur It's *mostly* O(1). There may be some bad hashing overloading buckets, but done right the load factor will be low enough to call it O(1). The hash function itself may be a brute, but who's to say that O(1) can't take 13.7 billion years?

Comment: @user4581301 Agree, still need to think about possible hashing issues.