# Time complexity of insert() in unordered_map when adding a std::vector as a value

Tags: c++, unordered-map

If I have an `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>` and I want to insert an array with a specific key. Suppose the vector has size M. If the insertion succeeds, is the time complexity O(1) on average or O(M)? Example code:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> dictionary;
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
dictionary.insert(1, vec);
```

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/), we will do a copy when we insert the element. So I think the answer should be O(M) (i.e., linear to the size of the array)?

This is **not** a duplicate of [c++ - unordered_map complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470948/c-unordered-map-complexity) because I am not asking the lookup time of a c++ hash map in general. My question is for a specific scenario: when calling **insert()** of an `std::unordered_map` with a `std::vector` as an element, will the O(1) average time still hold (suppose we cannot view the size of the vector as a constant)?

Comment: why are you asking? You can also construct the vector in place via `std::map::emplace`

Comment: I know I can use emplace() but I just want to know if the insert() includes copy an array, will it make the time complexity not O(1)?

Comment: for a given element to insert, `insert`s complexity depends on the size of the map and is guaranteed to be constant on average. For a given map, inserting m-sized vectors via copying is of course `O(M)`, but thats not what complexity of insert is concerned about. Also note that `insert` might move the vector which is not `O(M)`. I think your question is mainly about terminology and the answer is: No, the complexity to insert a single element is still said to be `O(1)` on average. For details see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)

Comment: in that sense, imho the duplicate does answer you question when taken literally, modulo a small misunderstanding what complexity is about. no matter how `insert` is implemented (moving aside) it cannot change the fact that copying a m-sized vector requires to copy m elements, hence there is no point in including that into the complexity of insert its just a "constant" factor from the point of view of `insert`